# Deploying Docker image to AWS ECS using Jenkins

Tags: dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I created a sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Angelina1984/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup) and I would like to accomplish following on every PR:

1. Build React application and get it running inside a Docker container
2. Using pipeline build the Docker image
3. Using pipeline, push the image to corporate Docker Hub
4. Using pipeline, take the Docker image from corporate Docker Hub and deploy it into AWS Elastic Container Service
5. Allow React application to listen on a port, it doesn't have to be open to public, it could be just accessible if you are on corporate VPN

I followed [this tutorial](https://tomgregory.com/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-into-aws-with-jenkins/) and I am stuck on step 4. above, pushing image to ECS. Do I need to use `gradle` or can I do all this in `Jenkinsfile`?

Here is what I have so far:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Jenkinsfile

```
artifactoryHost = "sten-docker.art-bobcat.sten.com"
buildContainerVersion = "1.0"
imageName = "team-docker/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup"
fullImageName = artifactoryHost + "/" + imageName
versionedImageName = fullImageName  + ":" + buildContainerVersion


pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'build-internal-use-containers'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "npm install"
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh "npm test"
            }
        }

        stage('Build Docker image') {
            steps {
                sh "docker build -t ${versionedImageName} ."
            }
        }

        stage("Push Docker image") {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry("https://"+ artifactoryHost,'svc_d_artifactory'){
                      sh """
                          docker push ${versionedImageName}
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy image to AWS') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry(httpsPrefix + artifactoryHost, 'svc_d_artifactory'){
                        withAWS(credentials: "aws_vcs_dev_vpc", region: "us-east-1") {
                            sh './gradlew awsCfnMigrateStack awsCfnWaitStackComplete -PsubnetId=$SUBNET_ID -PdockerHubUsername=$DOCKER_HUB_LOGIN_USR -Pregion=$REGION'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ecs.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: 'Account/VPC CFN configuration'
Parameters:
  SubnetID:
    Type: String
  ServiceName:
    Type: String
  ServiceVersion:
    Type: String
  DockerHubUsername:
    Type: String
Resources:
  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: deployment-example-cluster
  ServiceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: ServiceSecurityGroup
      GroupDescription: Security group for service
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 8080
          ToPort: 8080
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: !Sub ${ServiceName}-task
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 512
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Sub ${ServiceName}-container
          Image: !Sub ${DockerHubUsername}/${ServiceName}:${ServiceVersion}
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 8080
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - EC2
        - FARGATE
  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub ${ServiceName}-service
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          Subnets:
            - !Ref SubnetID
          SecurityGroups:
            - !GetAtt ServiceSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'jp.classmethod.aws.cloudformation'

version = scmVersion.version

cloudFormation {
    stackName "$project.name-stack"
    stackParams([
        SubnetID: findProperty('subnetId') ?: '',
        ServiceName: project.name,
        ServiceVersion: project.version,
        DockerHubUsername: dockerHubUsernameProperty
    ])
    templateFile project.file("ecs.yml")
}
```

Comment: Is it working outside corporate network ? In corporate network firewall will be blocking connection. and jenkins has plugins that can do this such as https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecs/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will 100% match your scenario, since you're using Cloud Formation, but still using Jenkins we just open-sourced our "glueing" tool for doing so:

https://github.com/GuccioGucci/yoke

Probably issue with networking would be more on provisioning, that we're managing with Terraform, decoupling from application deployment.